# How can i redirect specific URL with query string in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to redirect all url that contains word "form" to my homepage.

In my htaccess file i have written

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)form(.*)$ https://mywebsite/? [L,R=301]
```

and its working for these urls

```
https://mywebsite/downloadform.php?form='abc'
```

but not working for

```
https://mywebsite/cn/cn/downloadform.php?form=''abc''
```

Please suggest me a rule that will redirect the above urls to homepage
Thank you

Comment: The rule you posted will certainly get applied in both situations. You are either looking at cached results or you have some _additional_ configuration setup you did not tell us about.

Comment: FYI, to just match `form` anywhere in the requested path, you don’t need `^(.*)form(.*)$` - just `form` will do.